# How to run ImageMagick library scripts in Windows with Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, imagemagick

I have reviewed many posts, but I did not find a solution to run ImageMagick scripts in Windows with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), despite configuring them [following this post](https://cvisiondemy.com/install-imagemagick-textcleaner-script-on-windows/).  It fails with an error

> FILE ./0004.jpg DOES NOT EXIST OR IS NOT AN ORDINARY FILE, NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO SIZE

Below is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using the cygwin ImageMagick package

```
$ cygcheck -l ImageMagick | grep bin
/usr/bin/animate.exe
/usr/bin/compare.exe
/usr/bin/composite.exe
/usr/bin/conjure.exe
/usr/bin/convert.exe
/usr/bin/display.exe
/usr/bin/identify.exe
/usr/bin/import.exe
/usr/bin/mogrify.exe
/usr/bin/montage.exe
/usr/bin/stream.exe
```

The program you are calling is not a cygwin one so it does not understand the `./file` format.

```
$ cygcheck -p testdeskew
Found 0 matches for testdeskew
```